# Add numbers in row javascript

Tags: javascript

I am relatively new to javascript. This is my third month in this class I am taking and right now we are making a golf score card. I have a table that holds the golf score card data.

Holes   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18

Blue:   494 217 445 226 391 385 488 173 419 488 205 491 384 175 437 224 441 491

White:  478 206 436 189 372 371 452 159 393 438 185 479 370 150 422 195 429 471

Par:    5   3   4   3   4   4   5   3   4   5   3   5   4   3   4   3   4   5

Red:    463 174 422 154 356 355 421 148 374 434 166 467 357 131 361 161 383 455

The yardages appear using this

```
    function addInfo(num) {
    document.getElementById(num + 23).innerHTML = model.course.holes[num].tee_boxes[0].yards;
    document.getElementById(num + 45).innerHTML = model.course.holes[num].tee_boxes[1].yards;
    document.getElementById(num + 111).innerHTML = model.course.holes[num].tee_boxes[0].par;
    document.getElementById(num + 177).innerHTML = model.course.holes[num].tee_boxes[2].yards;

}
```

I want to create a total box for the blue white and red tee boxes.How can I add together all the yardages for the tee boxes as they appear.
I can do this for one row, but its not dynamic:

```
    document.getElementById(43).innerHTML = (+(document.getElementById(23).innerHTML)+ +(document.getElementById(24).innerHTML)+ +(document.getElementById(25).innerHTML)+ +(document.getElementById(26).innerHTML)+ +(document.getElementById(27).innerHTML)+ +(document.getElementById(28).innerHTML)+ +(document.getElementById(29).innerHTML)+ +(document.getElementById(30).innerHTML)+ +(document.getElementById(31).innerHTML)+ +(document.getElementById(32).innerHTML)+ +(document.getElementById(33).innerHTML)+ +(document.getElementById(34).innerHTML)+ +(document.getElementById(35).innerHTML)+ +(document.getElementById(36).innerHTML)+ +(document.getElementById(37).innerHTML)+ +(document.getElementById(38).innerHTML)+ +(document.getElementById(39).innerHTML)+ +(document.getElementById(40).innerHTML));
```

Comment: show us the `html` and any attempts you've made...

Comment: @WhiteHat I edited it and put it in my question.

Comment: don't see any `html`. the argument for `getElementById` should match an element on the page, for example... `<td id="hole-1">`). you can try converting `innerHTML` to a `Number(...innerHTML)`

Comment: the document.getElementById(23) is the id for that cell. that was just my way of adding the cells together. @WhiteHat

Comment: @WhiteHat the document.getElementById(num+23); is the Id for the <td> I can't show you the 'html' because I am creating it dynamically using a for loop

Comment: var allTd = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
    for (var i = 0; i < allTd.length; i++) {
        allTd[i].setAttribute("width", "25px");
        allTd[i].setAttribute("height", "25px");
        allTd[i].setAttribute("class", "allTds");
        allTd[i].setAttribute("id", i);

Comment: add that to the question, that _is_ the `html`, at least in part, we need to see...

Answer (score 0):

Make an input type to store 3 things:

```
    <input type="hidden" value="0" id="blueScore1"/>
    <input type="hidden" value="0" id="blueScore2"/>
    <input type="hidden" value="0" id="blueTotalScore"/>
```

Do that for every color, then after you've done that, make an if else statement suggesting which input ids you are using. so the front 9 ids go to score1 the back 9 go to score 2 and the total are them added together.

Lastly the way you store the information is by this:

```
    var blueTotalScore = (+(document.getElementById("blueTotalScore").value) + +(model.course.holes[num].tee_boxes[0].yards);
    document.getElementById("43).innerHTML = blueTotalScore;
```

then just do that for every score and color.